# Conditions to to have $\rho(I-aM)<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

Let $M$ be a non-symmetric matrix with complex eigenvalues $m_1,\dots, m_n$. Why, in order to prove $\rho(I-aM)<1$, does it suffice to show that $\mathrm{Re}\{m_j\} > 0$?

*Notations*: $\rho$ is the spectral radius operator while $\mathrm{Re}\{\cdot\}$ operator returns the real part of a complex number.

Comment: It does not suffice. Could you tell us where you encountered this statement?

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for the interest. I encountered [here](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Constrained-Opt.pdf), p. 232, below eq. 7.

Comment: I think the key here is "for $\alpha$ sufficiently small". We want to prove that **there exists** some $\bar \alpha > 0$ such that $\rho(I - \alpha M) < 1$ whenever $\alpha \in (0,\bar \alpha]$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Is it possible to elaborate a little more? I do not see any $\alpha$ in the presenting proof. Also why is working with the real parts. A pedagogical answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the text: "the proof consists of showing that, for $\alpha$ sufficiently small, the hypothesis of Ostrowski's theorem is satisfied". In this case, we want to show that the matrix $B$ is such that, **for sufficiently small $\alpha$**, $\rho(I - \alpha B) < 1$. To show that this is the case, it suffices to show that the real parts of the eigenvalues of $B$ have strictly positive real part. The proof proceeds to do this, allowing us to reach the desired conclusion.

> **Claim:** If the eigenvalues of $B$ have strictly positive real parts, then there exists some $\bar \alpha > 0$ such that $\rho(I - \alpha B) < 1$ for all $\alpha \in (0,\bar \alpha]$.

*Proof:* Let $m_k = p_k + iq_k$ denote the $k$th eigenvalue of $B$. The eigenvalues of $I - \alpha B$ will be of the form $\lambda_k = 1 - \alpha m_k$ for $k = 1,\dots,n$. We note that
$$
|1 - \alpha m_k|^2 = (1 - \alpha p_k)^2 + (\alpha q_k)^2 = (p_k^2 + q_k^2)\alpha^2 - 2p_k \alpha + 1.
$$
For each $k$, we may consider the quadratic function $f_k:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
f_k(\alpha) = (p_k^2 + q_k^2)\alpha^2 - 2p_k \alpha + 1.
$$
Each $f_k$ satisfies $f_k(0) = 1$ and achieves a minimum at
$$
\alpha = \bar \alpha_k := \frac{p_k}{p_k^2 + q_k^2} > 0.
$$
Each function $f_k$ is strictly decreasing over the interval $[0,\bar \alpha_k]$. Now, define
$$
\bar \alpha = \min_{k = 1,\dots,n} \bar \alpha_k.
$$
From our observations so far, we can conclude that for each $k = 1,\dots,n$, $f_k(\alpha)$ will be less than $f(0) = 1$ for each $\alpha \in (0,\bar \alpha]$. That is, for each $\alpha \in (0,\bar \alpha]$, the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ of $I - \alpha B$ will all satisfy $|\lambda_k|^2 < 1$, which is to say that we have $\rho(I - \alpha B) < 1$.

$\hspace{300 pt}\square$

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. The only point  I could not catch entirely is the $\min$ part. What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: @Thoth I know that each $f_k$ is less than $1$ at each $\alpha$ from the interval $(0,\bar \alpha_k]$. If I want **all** of the $f_k$ to be less than $1$, then I need $\alpha$ to be taken from the **intersection** of these intervals. The intersection of these intervals is $(0,\bar \alpha]$, where $\bar \alpha$ is the minimum of the $\bar \alpha_k$.